# Is there a way to access inputs when creating custom loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a quite complex CNN network, where I have **3 different inputs** and **6 outputs**. I need to create a loss function, where one of the inputs influences the loss computation.

I tried going along [custom loss function tutorial](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/04/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-metrics.html), but when I use the model input as parameter and use it in calculations I get:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (add_5:0) to a
>   numpy array.

After debugging, I realized that the mentioned input never gets actual values, it stays tensor of shape (None, None, None), while expected_y and predicted_y gets real data shapes (10, 46, 46, 19).

Code of custom loss function (*model* param is model used in fit_generator):

```
def custom_loss(model):
    def loss(y, gt):
        # W is the background weight
        W = model.inputs[-1][:, :, :, -1]
        print(y.shape)
        print(W.shape)
        return K.sum(K.square(y - gt) * W) / c.BATCH_SIZE / 2

    return loss
```

Can I access the data flowing through model, not just placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding identical layer (which I need) to all outputs, then custom loss takes information from that layer and applies it on default calculations of custom MSE as described in the question.

Still the question of how to access network input in loss remains unanswered and I am interested in any possible insight.